# Need a guide to access my ropsten test network contracts through my command line and not remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, ropsten, access

I have written and published a contract on the ropsten test network using remix. Now I want to access the functions of the smart contract from my command line (My PC) and not the remix IDE. Is there a way to do this?

**Note:**
I have my contract address.

Comment: Yes, install NodeJS, run `npm install web3`, write a script and run it from command line using `node`.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes but, how do I access my contract functions from the cmd?

Comment: You call those functions from your script. It's actually better than Remix, because you can automate whatever it is that you want to do (instead of doing it manually, one function at a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [Truffle console](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-truffle-develop-and-the-console)

It allows call functions of smart contracts directly from your console.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts from that link here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.

Comment: @Chenmunka I provided link to the documentation of truffle console functionality. It allows do thing asked in this question. I can actually copy/past documentation, but I don't think it will be really useful. Anyone who wants to find a way to access smart contract from cmd can use link I posted above, thanks.

Comment: I used the web3js solution with truffle framework! So thanks!!